# Deployment Manager update error: Deployment in preview must not have a target with UPDATE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

Every time I try to run an update through deployment manager to an existing deployment in preview, I get the error:

```
$ gcloud deployment-manager deployments update abc --config abc.yaml
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) ResponseError: code=400, message=Invalid value for field 'resource.target': ''.  Deployment in preview must not have a target with UPDATE
```

However, if I don't use the update on the gcloud command line and go to the console and click 'deploy' the update goes through fine.

What can be causing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just ran into this, I wasn't following the instructions properly.  After you created something in preview you do NOT pass the config again you just apply.

create preview

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments update my-deployment --config my-config.yaml --preview
```

run deployment

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments update my-deployment
```

Docs
https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/updating-deployments#make_the_update_request

Comment: This actually makes so much more sense. But i swear the documentation wasn't there when i explored this a year back. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Cancel the preview and then run the deployment update again.

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments cancel-preview DEPLOYMENT
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue on our end. We are currently working on a fix; I cannot provide an ETA for the fix at the moment. I strongly suggest continuing to use the work around you’ve found by deploying through the console.

Comment: Any updates on this one? I also experienced this and this looks like the type of issue w/c can be easily encountered

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I was calling the update API for applying the preview with the full `body` parameter that I passed when first creating the preview.

The fix was to pass only the `fingerprint` and `name` properties in the `body` parameter for the preview-apply call.

```
project_name = '...'
deployment_name = '...'

existing_deployment = service.deployments().get(
    project=project_name,
    deployment=deployment_name).execute()

service.deployments().update(
    project=project_name,
    deployment=deployment_name,
    body={
        'name': deployment_name,
        'fingerprint': existing_deployment["fingerprint"],
    },
    preview=False).execute()
```