# Update an existing deployment using deployment manager update API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I use Java APIs for the CRUD operations of the google cloud deployment manager API. I can create, preview, delete deployments OK.

But when I try to update an existing deployment that's in preview mode, the API returns the below error.

***Deployment in preview must not have a target with UPDATE***

The same inputs works OK for create and preview. So, I'm sure that the inputs are OK.

I looked up for others who have reported this issue. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203811/deployment-manager-update-error-deployment-in-preview-must-not-have-a-target-wi/52208016#52208016) is one such report but no solution.

Does anyone know if there's a  git hub repo for google cloud deployment manager where we can report this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203811), is a known issue and you can still use the workaround suggested.

I have created an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130284855) for this error message. So, you can add your comments there and follow up for upcoming updates.